# Replacing values in a list based on the number of consecutive values they area a part of

Tags: r

I have the following list:

```
my_list <- list(c(1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0), c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
> my_list
[[1]]
 [1] 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

Wherever there are fewer than four consecutive `1`s, I would like to replace those `1`s with `0`s. The resulting list should look like this:

```
> my_new_list
[[1]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

I believe I have to use the `rle` and `inverse.rle` functions, but I can't figure out how to do it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each list component use `rle` and replace each `values` element with 0 if its `lengths` is less than or equal to `max_n`, wich defaults to 3.  Then perform the inverse of `rle` to get back the resulting vector.

```
replace_zeros <- function(x, max_n = 3) {
  r <- rle(x)
  r$values[r$lengths <= max_n] <- 0
  inverse.rle(r)
}
lapply(my_list, replace_zeros)
```

giving:

```
[[1]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0

[[2]]
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0

[[3]]
 [1] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks. How would I do this in 3 separate steps? For example: `list1 <- lapply(my_list, function(x) rle(x))`, then followed by the `values` and `lengths` line of code, and finally followed by the `inverse.rle` step?

Comment: The three functions would be `rle`, `function(r, max_n = 3) { r$values[r$lengths <= max_n] <- 0; r }` and `inverse.rle` .

Comment: Thanks. The last `r` from the second function is short for `return(r)`, right?

Comment: Yes, a function always returns the value of the last statement in it that is executed.